# Ajax trigger redirect after submit

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have 2 ajax scripts, 1 for upload photos and 1 for upload form. Both are triggered from the same button. What i want is to redirect to another page after photos are uploaded and if there is not photo to upload i still want to redirect but after form is subbmited.
Here is the gallery upload script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            $(\'#uploader_div\').ajaxupload({
                url:\'upload.php\',
                remotePath:\'images/users/'.$id.'/\',
                bootstrap:true,
                maxFileSize:\'50M\' ,
                form:\'parent\',
                //function that triggers when all files are uploaded
                finish: function(file_names, file_obj){
                 window.location=\'profil.php?user='.$id.'\';
                }

            });
            </script>
```

Here is the form code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var f = $(\'form\');

    var b = $(\'#submit1\'); // upload button


    b.click(function(){
        f.ajaxForm({
            beforeSend: function(){

            },
            success: function(e){

            },
            error: function(e){

            }
        });
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: Use `window.location.href = "profil.php?user='.$id.'";`

Comment: In both cases you want to redirect to same page or two different pages?

Comment: both cases same page, but when i have images to upload i want to redirect after they are on server, if not i just want to redirect even if i dont have images, to same page yea